# Docker-compose version3 data volume container

Tags: docker-compose

I´m having problems getting data volume containers running in docker-compose v3. As a test I´ve tried to connect two simple images like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  assets:
    image: cpgonzal/docker-data-volume
    container_name: data_container
    command: /bin/true
    volumes:
      - assets_volume:/tmp
  web:
    image: python:3
    volumes:
      - assets_volume:/tmp
    depends_on:
      - assets

volumes:
    assets_volume:
```

I would expect that python:3 container can see /tmp of data_container. Unfortunately

```
docker-compose up
```

fails with

```
data_container exited with code 0
desktop_web_1 exited with code 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that images exist? (`docker images`). Second, note that you haven't defined any entry point. Try to start with command: `/bin/bash -c "sleep infinity"` for example and then `docker exec -ti container_name` to inspect behaviour from a shell. Sorry, I need more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your containers exited because there's no command to keep it running.

Use these three options: stdin_open, tty, and command to keep it running.

Here's an example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    image: node:8
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: sh
```